# Call function twice with different parameters

Tags: javascript, html

My Code works for 1 canvas. But **I need this implementation to work for 2 of canvas**.

So I tried

```
  var SIGNATURE_2 = new CLIPBOARD_CLASS("signatureCanvas2", true);
```

The problem is that this always pastes the image in the first canvas, I just need to press Ctrl+V. 
**How do I paste ONLY when the canvas is focused or hovered?**

```js
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Copy paste Image to Canvas
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    var SIGNATURE = new CLIPBOARD_CLASS("signatureCanvas", true);
    var SIGNATURE_2 = new CLIPBOARD_CLASS("signatureCanvas2", true);

    /**
     * image pasting into canvas
     * 
     * @param {string} canvas_id - canvas id
     * @param {boolean} autoresize - if canvas will be resized
     */
    function CLIPBOARD_CLASS(canvas_id, autoresize) {
        var _self = this;
        var canvas = document.getElementById(canvas_id);
        var ctx = document.getElementById(canvas_id).getContext("2d");
        var ctrl_pressed = false;
        var command_pressed = false;
        var paste_event_support;
        var pasteCatcher;

        //handlers
        document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
            _self.on_keyboard_action(e);
        }, false); //firefox fix
        document.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
            _self.on_keyboardup_action(e);
        }, false); //firefox fix
        document.addEventListener('paste', function (e) {
            _self.paste_auto(e);
        }, false); //official paste handler

        //constructor - we ignore security checks here
        this.init = function () {
            pasteCatcher = document.createElement("div");
            pasteCatcher.setAttribute("id", "paste_ff");
            pasteCatcher.setAttribute("contenteditable", "");
            pasteCatcher.style.cssText = 'opacity:0;position:fixed;top:0px;left:0px;width:10px;margin-left:-20px;';
            document.body.appendChild(pasteCatcher);

            // create an observer instance
            var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
                mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
                    if (paste_event_support === true || ctrl_pressed == false || mutation.type != 'childList'){
                        //we already got data in paste_auto()
                        return true;
                    }

                    //if paste handle failed - capture pasted object manually
                    if(mutation.addedNodes.length == 1) {
                        if (mutation.addedNodes[0].src != undefined) {
                            //image
                            _self.paste_createImage(mutation.addedNodes[0].src);
                        }
                        //register cleanup after some time.
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            pasteCatcher.innerHTML = '';
                        }, 20);
                    }
                });
            });
            var target = document.getElementById('paste_ff');
            var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };
            observer.observe(target, config);
        }();
        //default paste action
        this.paste_auto = function (e) {
            paste_event_support = false;
            if(pasteCatcher != undefined){
                pasteCatcher.innerHTML = '';
            }
            if (e.clipboardData) {
                var items = e.clipboardData.items;
                if (items) {
                    paste_event_support = true;
                    //access data directly
                    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                        if (items[i].type.indexOf("image") !== -1) {
                            //image
                            var blob = items[i].getAsFile();
                            var URLObj = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
                            var source = URLObj.createObjectURL(blob);
                            this.paste_createImage(source);
                        }
                    }
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
                else {
                    //wait for DOMSubtreeModified event              
                }
            }
        };
        //on keyboard press
        this.on_keyboard_action = function (event) {
            var k = event.keyCode;
            //ctrl
            if (k == 17 || event.metaKey || event.ctrlKey) {
                if (ctrl_pressed == false)
                    ctrl_pressed = true;
            }
            //v
            if (k == 86) {
                if (document.activeElement != undefined && document.activeElement.type == 'text') {
                    //let user paste into some input
                    return false;
                }

                if (ctrl_pressed == true && pasteCatcher != undefined){
                    pasteCatcher.focus();
                }
            }
        };
        //on kaybord release
        this.on_keyboardup_action = function (event) {
            //ctrl
            if (event.ctrlKey == false && ctrl_pressed == true) {
                ctrl_pressed = false;
            }
            //command
            else if(event.metaKey == false && command_pressed == true){
                command_pressed = false;
                ctrl_pressed = false;
            }
        };
        //draw pasted image to canvas
        this.paste_createImage = function (source) {
            var pastedImage = new Image();
            pastedImage.onload = function () {
                if(autoresize == true){
                    //resize
                    canvas.width = pastedImage.width;
                    canvas.height = pastedImage.height;
                }
                else{
                    //clear canvas
                    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                }
                ctx.drawImage(pastedImage, 0, 0);
            };
            pastedImage.src = source;
        };
    }
```

```css
.signatureCanvas {
    border:1px solid #027C8C;
    width: 100%;
    max-height:200px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="signatureCanvas" class="signatureCanvas"></canvas>
 
  <canvas id="signatureCanvas2" class="signatureCanvas"></canvas>
```

**PS: Please just open snipping tool on windows and copy paste an image to test**

Comment: The problem is your event listeners: You listen for 'keydown', 'keyup', and 'paste' events at the document level. How exactly are you going to know which canvas to apply it to, if you're attaching to a global event?

Comment: That's my problem. I don't know. I just want to click on the canvas to focus or hover it and then paste in which canvas I chose. **If I call that function again it pastes on both canvas, I dont want that**

Comment: You will likely need to involve another layer, like a modal/popup to select where you want the paste to go. A paste event cannot really be tied to a specific element any other way.

Comment: Please do you know how to do this? This is extremely advanced for me

Comment: I do know how to do this.

Comment: **All around me are familiar faces....**

Comment: Is there anyone that works at Google that knows this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add click event to select proper canvas:

```
    canvas_ids.forEach(function(canv) {
        document.getElementById(canv).addEventListener('click',     function (e) {
            canvas = document.getElementById(canv);
            ctx = document.getElementById(canv).getContext("2d");
        }, false);
    });
```

Then you have to change CLIPBOARD_CLASS creation.

```
var SIGNATURE= new CLIPBOARD_CLASS(["signatureCanvas","signatureCanvas2"], true);
```

To ensure that by default first canvas is selected you have to change:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById(canvas_ids[0]);
var ctx = document.getElementById(canvas_ids[0]).getContext("2d");
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L2nvhqe8/)

Comment: You may also add special css class to mark which canvas is selected.

Comment: Interesting solution.

Answer (score 0):

I might remove the handlers from the class wholesale and have one simple `keyup` event.

In this example the `keyup` handler is attached to the document element. When it's fired it calls `handleKeyUp` which checks to see what elements are being hovered over. The canvas will be the last element in the nodelist. Here the code grabs that and then paints/unpaints it red. Hover over the two canvases and then press a key and you'll see what I mean.

```js
document.addEventListener('keyup', handleKeyUp, false);

function handleKeyUp(e) {
  const hovers = document.querySelectorAll(':hover');
  const canvas = hovers[hovers.length - 1];
  paint(canvas); // or call a class method to paste to your canvas etc
}

function paint(c) {
  const isActive = c.classList.contains('active');
  isActive ? c.classList.remove('active') : c.classList.add('active');
}
```

```css
canvas {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

canvas.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="signatureCanvas" class="active"></canvas>
<canvas id="signatureCanvas2"></canvas>
```

It seems a bit easier to do it this way.